# Extract values from vector of maps conditionally in clojure

Tags: clojure

This code extracts all values from vector of maps.

```
(def vector-of-maps [{:a "1" :b "2"}{:a "3" :b "4"}])
(mapcat vals vector-of-maps)
```

so I get
("1" "2" "3" "4")

I want to get values only from **:a** to get
("1" "3")

What way can I do it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(def vector-of-maps [{:a "1" :b "2"} {:a "3" :b "4"}])
(map :a vector-of-maps)
```

yields

```
("1" "3")
```

`map` will apply `:a` as a function which will extract value from each value in `vector-of-maps`.

Comment: Heh, this'll teach me to answer questions when I've been awake for exactly 15 minutes. :P

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
(map val (filter (comp #{:a} key) (apply concat vector-of-maps)))
```

Explanation:

1. `apply concat` converts a sequence of maps to a sequence of all the key-value pairs from all those maps
2. `filter (comp #{:a} key)` keeps only the key-value pairs whose keys are in the one-element set `#{:a}`
3. `map val` gets the value from each remaining key-value pair

Example:

```
(def vector-of-maps [{:a "1" :b "2"} {:a "3" :b "4"}])

(map val (filter (comp #{:a} key) (apply concat vector-of-maps)))
;=> ("1" "3")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!